# Modifying TLS cipher suites for a Google Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to restrict TLS ciphers for a service we run on Google Cloud Run that exposes its API using Google Endpoints.

Those Endpoints use some sort of proxy ([envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.1/) from what I've read).

[Here's](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options#cloud_run_for_serverless_platforms) how it should work. We are concerned with the second half, because we want to set up `ssl_server_cipher_suites` (at least I hope) to contain commas.

The docker container with the proxy is deployed to those Endpoints, I added it to the Dockerfile.

```
ENV ESPv2_ARGS ^++^--ssl_server_cipher_suites="ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"++--enable_debug
```

When I deploy it, the service starts, and the log shows that the value has changed somewhere:

```
Starting Config Manager with args: ['bin/configmanager', '--logtostderr', '--rollout_strategy', 'fixed', '--backend_address', 'http://127.0.0.1:8082', '--v', '1', '--envoy_xff_num_trusted_hops', '0', '--listener_port', '8080', '--ssl_server_cipher_suites', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', '--service_json_path', '/etc/endpoints/service.json', '--compute_platform_override', 'Cloud Run(ESPv2)', '--suppress_envoy_headers=false']
```

But when I try to verify via `nmap`,it returns the same thing.

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 myapp.a.run.app
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-18 13:13 CEST
Nmap scan report for ...

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
…
```

The second flag (`--enable-debug`) works better - when it is there, there is more in the log. But the ciphers don't seem to apply. I also tried limiting TLS to TLSv1.3 only (`--ssl_minimum_protocol="TLSv1.3"`), but `nmap` kept returning TLSv1.2 as well.

Any ideas, please?